# MacBook charger not working when laptop is on

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

I am using original charger on MacBook Air. Of late my charger works if the computer turned off but not when it is on? Also when it is fully charged, it continue to charge. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:

1. Try resetting the SMC which stands for System Management Controller, sometimes it can cause this type of problems. Here is a link to a good article from Apple on how to do it: [Link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)
2. If possible, try an another charger and see if it charge properly with that one.
3. Take contact with Apple Support via phone or in your local Apple Store.

Hopefully any of these steps helped you in slowing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the little LED on the magsafe plug, it is not always working (on my MBA, so have to wiggle it) as a good indicator.

However the Battery status in the menu bar should show it.

In any case, I suggest to reset the SMC which is mainly responsible for power management. That might help in the assumption there is not another problem.

Look up SMC reset at Apple, for non removable battery models.